# how to fit text inside a HTML div

Tags: html, css

Hi I have div with some text 'Basic Details'. I want Details to be below Basic.

How can I achieve this.

Here is my jsbin
https://jsbin.com/dudine/edit?html,css,output

Sorry guys I dint include any code in here.

HTML

```css
 .textStyle {
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font-size: 90%;
   white-space: normal;
 }
 .left-rounded-corner {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   line-height: 16px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding-top: 10px;
   border-top-left-radius: 50px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
 }
 /*Allign elements in horizontally*/
 .element_align_horizontally {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div id='statusContainer' class='scrollable'>
  <div class="left-rounded-corner element_align_horizontally textStyle">Basic Details</div>
  <div class="rectangle-shape element_align_horizontally textStyle">two</div>
  <div class="rectangle-shape element_align_horizontally textStyle">three</div>
  <div class="rectangle-shape element_align_horizontally textStyle">Four</div>
  <div class="right-rounded-corner element_align_horizontally textStyle">Five</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help
Rao

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: `Basic<br>Details`

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.Even a few lines of code would have been nice for a good start to your doubtful journey of solving the mystery..! :D

Comment: You see you may be asking for something but clearly as your question isn't soo much clear so we can't give you any exact answer that's why you need to include a piece of code in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have included code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a few things to make this happen without extra markup...

```
.left-rounded-corner {
    ...
    line-height: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* include padding and margin in height */
    padding-top: 10px; /* move text down a bit */
}
.textStyle {
    ...
    font-size: 90%; /* something big enough to force wrap without extra markup */
    white-space: normal; /* allow wrapping */
}
```